# Storing chat logs in relational database

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, database-design

I am writing a chat bot that uses past conversations to generate its responses. Currently I use text files to store all the data but I want to use a database instead so that multiple instances of the bot can use it at the same time.

How should I structure this database?

My first idea was to keep a main table like `create table Sessions (startTime INT,ip INT, botVersion REAL, length INT, tableName TEXT)`. Then for each conversation I `create table <generated name>(timestamp INT, message TEXT)` with all the messages that were sent or received during that conversation. When the conversation is over, I insert the name of the new table into `Sessions(tableName)`. Is it ok to programmatically create tables in this manner? I am asking because most SQL tutorials seem to suggest that tables are created when the program is initialized.

Another way to do this is to have a huge `create table Messages(id INT, message TEXT)` table that stores every message that was sent or received. When a conversation is over, I can add a new entry to `Sessions` that includes the `id` used during that conversation so that I can look up all the messages sent during a certain conversation. I guess one advantage of this is that I don't need to have hundreds or thousands of tables.

I am planning on using SQLite despite its low concurrency since each instance of the bot may make thousands of reads before generating a response (which will result in one write). Still, if another relational database is better suited for this task, please comment.

Note: There are other questions on SO about storing chat logs in databases but I am specifically looking for how it should be structured and feedback on the above ideas.

Comment: I highly doubt that a table per conversation is the correct solution.

Comment: I doubt if storing a timestamp in an int is the right solution. btw:http://sourceforge.net/projects/wakkerbot/ wakkerbot stores both its input and its output (currently tweets) in a postgres DB. Input consists of 2M "blog" reactions, output about 2K postings and tweets. You can find (an older version of) the datamodel on SF.

Comment: @wildplasser Why is the timestamp a problem? I was planning on using a unix timestamp (seconds from epoch). IIRC SQLite INT is an int64 so it should not overflow.

Comment: Because in your queries you want to use plain-text human readable constants: `WHERE submission_date < '2011-10-20'`

Comment: timestamp in an int? Why start at 1358677887 when you can start at 1. Does time of message matter or just message order?

Comment: @wildplasser I see. Wouldn't it be faster to convert that to a unix time before making the query so there are no string comparisons? BTW most(all?) comparisons will be made relative to some other time such as the current time or the timestamp of a similar message.

Comment: @bmewsing Well, the main reason for timestamping is message order. In a later version however, I may use it for things like computing the typical time taken for a human to think and type a certain type of response.

Comment: You are new to databases? The constants are only parsed once (when the query is "compiled") I don't think that sql-lite stores dates in strings; normally date is an integral-like datatype. And, indeed, if you only need order you could just number them. And: don't be obsessed with speed and performance. Reading or writing a page to or from from disk costs 5..10 msec, calculating results from it, or manipulating it essentially nothing.

Comment: @wildplasser Yes, I am new to databases. The time used as a comparison is not constant (it may be the current time). Does this require that query is recompiled?

Comment: "compiled" into a machine-executable form, some kind of in-memory tree-like structure, which is executed by the actual DBMS engine. The comparison will be between the "raw" data read from the disk and the "parsed into raw" argument/constant from your query. And: at the time of query-execution it will be a constant. "current_time" := time of transaction/query-start.

Comment: @wildplasser SQLite doesn't have a very sophisticated understanding of time, so dates are either strings (the ISO format, in UTC, is probably best) or numbers (offset from epoch, like a Unix timestamp). If users aren't writing SQL directly — and let's face it, most don't — then either works. Semantically, they can capture slightly different things, of course, but does that matter here? And note that understanding “human” time is hard, horrendously so; there are whole specialist libraries on the topic…

Comment: Ok. I stand corrected. Maybe a time_t like thing or a simple sequenced int as enumeration will do better then.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a different table for each conversation. Instead add a "conversation" column to your single table.

Comment: If I do that, the `conversation` column would have to store every message in the conversation, right? I prefer to keep each message seprate

Comment: @Navin: Of course - that's called [normalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) (Ps: sorry it's Wiki).